# how can i solve my problem with php mailer that doesn't sent email

Tags: php, smtp

I want to make a working contact form to send email to me when a user fills the form. I wanted to use phpmailer since i use localhost with xampp. I have this code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    
    require "C:/xampp/htdocs/Composer/vendor/autoload.php";

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; 

    require "C:/xampp/htdocs/Composer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php";
    require "C:/xampp/htdocs/Composer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php";
    require "C:/xampp/htdocs/Composer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php";
?>
```

which is the header of my php file and the code to actually send the email:

```
<?php

                $message = "";                        

                if(isset($_POST["btn"]))
                {
                    $userName = $_POST["username"];
                    $userPhone = $_POST["userphone"];
                    $userEmail = $_POST["useremail"];
                    $userSubject = $_POST["usersubject"];
                    $userMessage = $_POST["usermessage"];
                    $toemail = "myemail";

                    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

                    try
                    {
                        $mail -> isSMTP();
                        $mail -> Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
                        $mail-> SMTPAuth = true;
                        $mail-> Username = 'myemail';
                        $mail-> Password = 'mypassword'; 
                        $mail-> SMTPSecure = 'tls';             
                        $mail-> Port = 587;

                        $mail -> setFrom($userEmail, $userName);
                        $mail -> addAddress($toemail);

                        $mail -> isHTML(false);
                        $mail -> Subject = $userSubject;
                        $mail -> Body = "Name: $userName\r\n" .
                                        "Phone: $userPhone\r\n" .
                                        "Message: $userMessage\r\n";

                        $mail -> send();
                        $message = "Your information has been received";
                    }
                    catch(Exception $e)
                    {
                        $message = "Error sending email. Please try again later";
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

But when i fill the form and click submit i get the error message which means that the try block doenst execute. I also get this error Undefined type PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer
in this line: `$mail = new PHPMailer(true);` and Undefined type PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception in this line: `catch(Exception $e)`. I have downloaded phpmailer and the composer and i have doublechecked the paths so i don't think these are the problem. The error are from the intelephense P1009. I also asked gpt but it said it is the paths or something like that but like i said i doublechecked them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure the form is getting posted properly, check your `btn` element has value

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

Get the `phpmailer` using `Composer`

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

then, in your code

```
require "path/to/vendor/autoload.php"; //PHPMailer Object
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; //PHPMailer class from the PHPMailer\PHPMailer namespace will be used in the current script
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; //Exception class from the PHPMailer\PHPMailer namespace will be used in the current script
```

and these three lines are not required, autoload saves the work

```
require "C:/xampp/htdocs/Composer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php";
require "C:/xampp/htdocs/Composer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php";
require "C:/xampp/htdocs/Composer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php";
```

Give it a try